# css prevent events

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have bumped with odd behaviour. I have set of checkbox input. On itself the following code works ok. But if integrate it into website when you press All button nothing happen

```
    $("[name*=group_]").live('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('name').substr(6,1);
        var cnt = $("[value!='all'][name*=group_"+id+"]:checked").length;

        if(cnt > 0){
            $("[value='all'][name*=group_"+id+"]").removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            $("[value='all'][name*=group_"+id+"]").attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    })

<fieldset class="subject">


                        <input type="checkbox" value="all" name="group_4" id="group_4"><label title="All" for="all">All</label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" value="15" id="cat_15" name="group_4[]"><label title="Maths" for="cat_15">Maths</label>

                                            <input type="checkbox" value="16" id="cat_16" name="group_4[]"><label title="English" for="cat_16">English</label>

                                            <input type="checkbox" value="14" id="cat_14" name="group_4[]"><label title="Science" for="cat_14">Science</label>

                    </fieldset>
```

Please go there http://jsfiddle.net/XXQTT/1/ and try  it with `Applicability`. When you click ex:`Early Years` it works but then if you click on `All` - nothing. I suppose its because of css but can't figure out how and how to make it work

Comment: live() is a deprecated function. You should be using on() as this code uses jquery 1.9.1. But this might not be your problem, just a comment...

Comment: @jtheman Iknow, there was on, just I thought different options and thought maybe live help and just haven't changed it yet. But that is not an issue

Comment: @JohnTravolta: To elaborate on what `jtheman` stated. The reason you should not use depracated features of jQuery is that features markes as depracated are usualy superceeded by more efficient ways. Also depracated features **may** be removed at any time without warning in any next version. Check the [depracated item list](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) for details. Generally reading the jQuery online documentation is something which is highly recommended, specially seeing how easy it is to read as it is written so well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is [value!='all'] - attribute selector doesn't have ! option.
Try replacing it with `$(":not([value='all'])[name*group_"+id+"]:checked")`

**Edit**

Based on feedback from `John Travolta`:

> 1. this works for me and returns correct value. 2. the problem there is no event generated. I put alert and there wasn't popup when you
>      click on All

Fair enough - the more you know! :D There's no bubbling of events on the All label, as tested with :

```
$('label').click(function() {
    window.alert('hi');
});

$('[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    window.alert('hello');
});
```

@edit - i'd blame it on script that handles label/input clicking, not css, as the following makes it work fine:

```
$('label').click(function() {
    $(this).prev("input:first").click();
});
```

Comment: jQuery provides an [attribute-not-equal](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) selector. It's not the most efficient method, but it's still valid code.

Comment: 1. this works for me and returns correct value. 2. the problem there is no event generated. I put alert and there wasn't popup when you click on All

Comment: Fair enough - the more you know! :D

There's no bubbling of events on the All label, as tested with `$('label').click(function(){ window.alert('hi'); }); $('[type=checkbox]').click(function(){ window.alert('hello'); });`

@edit - i'd blame it on script that handles label/input clicking, not css, as `$('label').click(function(){ $(this).prev("input:first").click();});` makes it work fine

Comment: @eithed: I have added your additional code to the answer. If you are posting additional code to complete/correct a solution change your answer instead of adding it in comments please. You don't need to add more code to your answer, you can even completely replace the answer with the current most accurate solution based on the feedback. That way it makes more sense to future users looking for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: @Francois - I'd disagree, as people will have to read comments underneath my answer to understand what's going on - so, I'll have to summarize all commenters answers :D But I can comply!

Comment: @eithed: I never read comments as they are usually a trail of research and clarifications mixed with other random statements of which the result should have formed a complete solution represented in the answer. In my humble oppinion having a partial working solution in the answer and leaving the rest of the complete solution scattered throughout comments, mixed with comments unrelated to clarifications and corrections is not very user friendly and may cause important information which is part of the complete solution to get lost.

Comment: @Francois - true, true. That's always best to leave final solution in the initial comment. Which I'll do, if I'll find it :)

Comment: @JohnTravolta - looking at the fiddle am more at loss :D I've fixed it a little - http://jsfiddle.net/XXQTT/2/

However - if I'm not mistaken, and you're using ajax for every input change, this approach will not work :)